# Java - Accessor methods without instance variables

Tags: java, objective-c, lombok

### Context

When programming in Objective-C, I'm used to never interact with instance variables directly. Instead, I use accessor methods that would act as a bridge between the methods and the instance variables. The `@property` keyword and the dot notation are perfect for implementing this while preserving the code appearance. When a property is declared, an instance variable and its accessor methods are created as well. I can customize any behaviour or decide to use or not instance variables by overriding the accessor methods.

I recently started to try to implement a similar (not identical) system in Java, by using [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org) `@Getter` and `@Setter` annotations. Everything is working fine, but there is a tiny specific detail bugging me: **If I want to declare a read-only property with no instance variable, I must not declare the variable**. This statement sounds obvious, but it's a matter of code organisation: I want to be able to list all properties in a 'Properties' section.

### Example

It might be easier to explain the situation by using an actual example. Here is a code fragment in Objective-C:

```
#pragma mark - Properties

@property (nonatomic, strong) Foo foo;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Bar bar;
@property (readonly) Baz baz;

#pragma mark - Getters / Setters

-(Bar)getBar {
    // Override bar getter. For example, perform lazy instantiation
    if(_bar == nil) {
        _bar = [[Bar alloc] init];
    }
    return _bar;
}
-(Baz)getBaz {
    // Override baz getter. For example, get baz from foo
    return self.foo.baz;
}

#pragma mark - Methods

-(void)doSomethingWithFooBarAndBaz {
    // Get log message
    NSString* logMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Foo: %@ Bar: %@ Baz: %@",
                                                      self.foo, self.bar, self.baz];
    // Log
    NSLog(logMessage);
}
```

I'm writing the Java version as follows:

```
@Accessors(prefix = "_")

...

// Properties

@Getter @Setter private Foo _foo;
@Setter private Bar _bar;
[THE PROBLEM IS HERE - I want to know that the baz property exists without
                       having to declare an instance variable for it]

// Getters / Setters

private Bar getBar() {
    // Implement bar getter. For example, perform lazy instantiation
    if(_bar == null) {
        _bar = new Bar();
    }
    return _bar;
}
private Baz getBaz() {
    // Implement baz getter. For example, get baz from foo
    return getFoo().getBaz();
}

// Methods

private void doSomethingWithFooBarAndBaz {
    // Get log message
    String logMessage = "Foo: " + getFoo().toString() + 
                       " Bar: " + getBar().toString() +
                       " Baz: " + getBaz().toString();
    // Log
    System.out.print(logMessage);
}
```

### Question

Is there a way to accomplish this? For now I'm doing declaring an instance variable and commenting it, like this:

```
@Getter @Setter private Foo _foo;
@Setter private Bar _bar;
// private Baz _baz;
```

But it just feels wrong. I'm wondering if there is an annotation that makes an instance variable unavailable at compile-time and runtime, thus making it purely informational, so I can do something like this:

```
@Getter @Setter private Foo _foo;
@Setter private Bar _bar;
@[ANNOTATION] private Baz _baz;
```

Any Ideas? Also, does this approach violates any Java best practices?

Comment: This is unclear. Why do you think declaring `_baz`, which is read-only should not be accomplished by declaring only a getter? Presumably its value will be set during construction or as a side-effect of some other operation.  This is what `@property (readonly) Baz baz;` accomplishes, so what's wrong with `@Getter private Baz _baz;`?

Comment: @JimGarrison in this particular case, the value from `baz` should be computed every time the `getBaz()` getter is called (a Computed Property in the Swift universe), not caching the result on an instance variable. If I write `@Getter private Baz _baz;` as you are suggesting, I will create an unused variable, since `_baz` won't be used on the getter implementation. I don't want this behaviour.

Comment: Just to make clear, in Objective-C, declaring a read-only property (`@property (readonly) Baz baz`) and implementing its getter (`-(Baz)getBaz`) WILL NOT create a `_baz` instance variable

Comment: I don't know which annotation library you're using, but why can't you just implement `getBaz()` without declaring an instance variable?  Can the annotation be applied to the method?

Comment: Consider the Objective-C example from my previous comment (read-only property declaration and getter implementation). If I remove the property declaration, the code would work the exact same way. That's because the property declaration is merely informative in this case. And that's what I want: information about properties. In Java, If I don't declare the instance variable, everything will indeed work, but I won't be able to visually know that there is a property, unless I check all the getters, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can do that only by creating method of "getter", like you did in your example.

Better pratice is to use foo.getBaz().